# MySQL - Optimise Query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have been left with a report which returns rows at an awfully slow rate. I feel I need to redo without so many or any sub-queries. But I am having a complete brain freeze to how to attempt this.

I have looked at indexes and the keys are not unique enough, which forces a full table scan time. Is there any way I can pull certain information from the other tables using a separate query, adding that as a variable and use it in the main query. As really the result of this query is only a few lines.

Are there any tips or tricks, that I could use to optimise or correct this SQL statement to speed it up.

(EDIT) I have added some create code for the tables.

```
SELECT
     case when (select count(ag.`PKEY`) - count(ag.`ANSWERTIME`)  from acdcallinformation ag
     where (ag.`COMPLETED`) = 1 and answertime is null and time(ag.INSTIME) and DATE_FORMAT(DATEOFCALL,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date(now()) and ag.skillid = acdcallinformation.skillid) is null
        then 0
            else
        (select count(ag.`PKEY`) - count(ag.`ANSWERTIME`)  from acdcallinformation ag where (ag.`COMPLETED`) = 1
        and answertime is null and DATE_FORMAT(DATEOFCALL,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date(now()) and ag.skillid = acdcallinformation.skillid)
     end as LostCalls,
     case when count(acdcallinformation.idleonqueue) is null then 0 else count(acdcallinformation.idleonqueue) end as CountCallsACD,
     case when count(acdcallinformation.`ANSWERTIME`) is null then 0 else count(acdcallinformation.`ANSWERTIME`) end AS acdcallinformation_ANSWERED,
     (select skillinfo.skillname from skillinfo where skillinfo.pkey = acdcallinformation.skillid) AS acdcallinformation_SKILLIDTEXT,

     (select count(pkey) from acdcallinformation age
       where DATE_FORMAT(DATEOFCALL,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date(now()) and age.skillid = acdcallinformation.skillid and   (age.`COMPLETED`) = 0 and answertime is null
        and SKILLID in (select SKILLID
                                from
                            callcenterinformation
                            where time > (now() - INTERVAL 5 SECOND) and callswaiting > 0)) as Waiting,

     -- count(acdcallinformation.`PKEY`) as CallsWaiting,
     acdcallinformation.`DATEOFCALL` AS acdcallinformation_DATEOFCALL,
     acdcallinformation.`FIRSTRINGONQUEUE` AS acdcallinformation_FIRSTRINGONQUEUE,
     case when acdcallinformation.`CONNECTTIME` is null then time('00:00:00') else acdcallinformation.`CONNECTTIME` end AS acdcallinformation_CONNECTTIME,
     acdcallinformation.`CALLSTATEBEFOREIDLE` AS acdcallinformation_CALLSTATEBEFOREIDLE,
     case when acdcallinformation.`AGENTRINGTIME` is null then time('00:00:00') else acdcallinformation.`AGENTRINGTIME` end AS acdcallinformation_AGENTRINGTIME,
     acdcallinformation.`IDLEONQUEUE` AS acdcallinformation_IDLEONQUEUE,
     acdcallinformation.`DDI` AS acdcallinformation_DDI,
     acdcallinformation.`CLIP` AS acdcallinformation_CLIP,
     acdcallinformation.`SKILLID` AS acdcallinformation_SKILLID,
     acdcallinformation.`ACTIONTYPE` AS acdcallinformation_ACTIONTYPE,
     acdcallinformation.`ACTIONDESTINATION` AS acdcallinformation_ACTIONDESTINATION,
     acdcallinformation.`COMPLETED` AS acdcallinformation_COMPLETED,
     acdcallinformation.`HANDLED` AS acdcallinformation_HANDLED,
     acdcallinformation.`CONFIRMED` AS acdcallinformation_CONFIRMED,
    (
        SELECT
         cal.`AGENTSREADY` AS callcenterinformation_AGENTSREADY
    FROM
         `callcenterinformation` cal
    WHERE cal.skillid <> 1 and acdcallinformation.skillid = skillid order by pkey desc limit 1,1) as agentsready
FROM
     `acdcallinformation` acdcallinformation
where DATE_FORMAT(DATEOFCALL,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date(now()- interval 1 day )
group by (select skillinfo.skillname from skillinfo where skillinfo.pkey = acdcallinformation.skillid);


CREATE TABLE `callcenterinformation` (
    `INSTIME` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `PKEY` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `SKILLID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `DATE` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `TIME` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `AGENTSLOGGEDIN` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `AGENTSREADY` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `AGENTSRINGING` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `AGENTSCONNECTED` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `AGENTSINPAUSE` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `AGENTSINWRAPUP` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `CALLSWAITING` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `COMPLETED` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `HANDLED` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `CONFIRMED` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`PKEY`),
    INDEX `DATE` (`DATE`),
    INDEX `TIME` (`TIME`),
    INDEX `SKILLID` (`SKILLID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `acdcallinformation` (
    `INSTIME` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `PKEY` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `DATEOFCALL` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `FIRSTRINGONQUEUE` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CONNECTTIME` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CALLSTATEBEFOREIDLE` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `AGENTRINGTIME` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ANSWERTIME` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `IDLEONQUEUE` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `DDI` TEXT NULL,
    `CLIP` TEXT NULL,
    `SKILLID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ACTIONTYPE` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ACTIONDESTINATION` TEXT NULL,
    `COMPLETED` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `HANDLED` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `CONFIRMED` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`PKEY`),
    INDEX `DATEOFCALL` (`DATEOFCALL`),
    INDEX `IDLEONQUEUE_HANDLED` (`IDLEONQUEUE`, `HANDLED`),
    INDEX `SKILLID` (`SKILLID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `skillinfo` (
    `INSTIME` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `PKEY` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `SKILLNAME` TEXT NULL,
    `CLIP` TEXT NULL,
    `WRAPUPTIMELENGTH` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `MAXRINGTIMELENGTH` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `FORCEDTICKET` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `STATEAFTERWRAPUP` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `STATEAFTERUNANSWEREDCALL` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ACTIONTYPE` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ACTIONDESTINATION` TEXT NULL,
    `DEFLECTAFTERCOURTESY` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `MAXOVERALLRINGTIMELENGTH` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `AUTOCLIP` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `OUTGOINGSETTINGSACTIVE` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `NUMPLANIDENTIFIER` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `TYPEOFNUMBER` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `CLIR` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `OUTGOINGROUTEID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `USELASTAGENT` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `CLIPROUTINGACTIVE` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `USETHRESHOLD` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `NORMALLOADTHRESHOLD` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `OVERLOADTHRESHOLD` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `STATEAFTERFORWARD` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `CALLDISTTYPE` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `USERGROUPID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `EXTERNALCONTROL` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `LASTAGENTLIMIT` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`PKEY`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too be honest, there is so much 'wrong' with this query it just isn't fun anymore =/

Some thoughts:

- `IFNULL()` is much more readable than `CASE WHEN <field> IS NULL THEN constant ELSE <field> END`, especially if  turns out to be a sub-query.
- AFAIK `COUNT(*)` will always return 0, even if nothing is found. Thus, there is no need to write an IFNULL() around it
- `COUNT(field)` only counts the non-NULL records for this field, but again, if nothing is found it will return 0, so no need for an IFNULL() around it
- You should teach yourself how to `JOIN` tables as it's (much) better practice than using correlated sub-queries all over the place.
- I don't know much about mysql, but it seems to me that you're killing your performance by putting casts and functions around the fields that otherwise seem to have a useful index. I'm pretty sure that due to these constructions the engine simply is not able to use said indexes causing performance to go down the drain. eg. I would try to rewrite

  - `AND DATE_FORMAT(DATEOFCALL,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date(now())` into something like `AND DATEOFCALL >= CUR_DATE()`, after all, both sides are dates (= numbers)
  - `DATE_FORMAT(DATEOFCALL,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date(now()- interval 1 day)` into `DATEOFCALL >= date(now()- interval 1 day)` for the very same reason
  - I'm also not sure what `time(ag.INSTIME)` should do ?!?! Is it true whenever the time is different from 00:00:00 ?
- I'm VERY surprised this query actually compiles at all as you seem to `GROUP BY` on just the `skillname`, but also fetch quite a lot of other fields from the table (e.g.  `idleonqueue`). From an MSSQL background that should not work.. I guess mysql is different although I do wonder what the result will be like.

Anyway, trying to apply some of the above to your query I end up with below. I doubt it will be 'much faster'; it might be just a bit, but I'd consider it a step forward in your mission to clean it up further...

Good luck!

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(ag.`PKEY`) - COUNT(ag.`ANSWERTIME`)  
          FROM acdcallinformation ag
         WHERE ag.`COMPLETED` = 1 
           AND answertime is null                     
           AND time(ag.INSTIME) 
           AND ag.DATEOFCALL >= CURDATE()             
           AND ag.skillid = info.skillid) AS LostCalls,
       COUNT(info.idleonqueue) AS CountCallsACD,
       COUNT(info.`ANSWERTIME`) AS acdcallinformation_ANSWERED,
       skillinfo.skillname AS acdcallinformation_SKILLIDTEXT,
       (SELECT COUNT(pkey) 
         FROM acdcallinformation age
        WHERE age.DATEOFCALL >= CURDATE() 
          AND age.skillid = info.skillid 
          AND age.`COMPLETED` = 0 
          AND age.answertime is null
          AND age.SKILLID IN (SELECT SKILLID
                                FROM callcenterinformation cci
                               WHERE cci.time > (now() - INTERVAL 5 SECOND) 
                                 AND cci.callswaiting > 0)) AS Waiting,
       -- count(info.`PKEY`) AS CallsWaiting,
       info.`DATEOFCALL` AS acdcallinformation_DATEOFCALL,
       info.`FIRSTRINGONQUEUE` AS acdcallinformation_FIRSTRINGONQUEUE,
       IFNULL(info.`CONNECTTIME`, time('00:00:00')) AS acdcallinformation_CONNECTTIME,
       info.`CALLSTATEBEFOREIDLE` AS acdcallinformation_CALLSTATEBEFOREIDLE,
       IFNULL(info.`AGENTRINGTIME`, time('00:00:00')) AS acdcallinformation_AGENTRINGTIME,
       info.`IDLEONQUEUE` AS acdcallinformation_IDLEONQUEUE,
       info.`DDI` AS acdcallinformation_DDI,
       info.`CLIP` AS acdcallinformation_CLIP,
       info.`SKILLID` AS acdcallinformation_SKILLID,
       info.`ACTIONTYPE` AS acdcallinformation_ACTIONTYPE,
       info.`ACTIONDESTINATION` AS acdcallinformation_ACTIONDESTINATION,
       info.`COMPLETED` AS acdcallinformation_COMPLETED,
       info.`HANDLED` AS acdcallinformation_HANDLED,
       info.`CONFIRMED` AS acdcallinformation_CONFIRMED,
       (SELECT cal.`AGENTSREADY` AS callcenterinformation_AGENTSREADY
          FROM `callcenterinformation` cal
         WHERE cal.skillid <> 1 
           AND cal.skillid = info.skillid 
         ORDER BY pkey DESC LIMIT 1,1) AS agentsready
  FROM `acdcallinformation` info
  JOIN `skillinfo`
    ON skillinfo.pkey = info.skillid
 WHERE info.DATEOFCALL >= (date(now()- interval 1 day ))
 GROUP BY skillinfo.skillname ;
```

Comment: Like to thank you for the very thorough response. I will investigate some of the ideas, especially conversion on fields where it may not be necessary. Plus, yes this may increase speeds, due to it already having indexes, maybe. More important, casting on a field not using the index. I had never thought about it before.